# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. On mapping filtered object/array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am making a tab of projects and I keep getting an error in the browser console. Although the page is rendering fine, I keep getting an error on the browser console.

Here is my Multimedia.js page

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Col, Container, Nav, Row, Tab } from "react-bootstrap";
import ProjectEmpty from "../../components/ProjectEmpty";
import ProjectCard from "../../components/ProjectCard";

export default function Multimedia() {
    const [projMultimedia, setProjMultimedia] = useState();
    const [projKey, setProjKey] = useState(0);
    const [isMultimediaEmpty, setIsMultimediaEmpty] = useState(true);
    const handleProjKeySelect = (e) => setProjKey(e);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/project/all`, {
            method: 'GET'
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setProjMultimedia(data.filter(proj => proj.category === "multimedia"));
        })
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof projMultimedia !== 'undefined' && projMultimedia.length !== 0) {
            setIsMultimediaEmpty(false);
        }
        else {
            setIsMultimediaEmpty(true);
        }
    }, [projMultimedia]);

    return (
        <Container fluid id="project-list" className="h-100">
        {isMultimediaEmpty
        ? <ProjectEmpty />
        :
            <Tab.Container id="projNav" defaultActiveKey="0" activeKey={projKey} onSelect={handleProjKeySelect}>
                <Row className="flex-column flex-lg-row">
                    <Col xs={12} lg={2} className="proj-tabs p-0 flex-shrink-1">
                        <Nav className="proj-nav d-lg-flex flex-lg-column">
                            {projMultimedia.map((project, index) => (
                                <Nav.Item>
                                    <Nav.Link eventKey={index}>{project.title}</Nav.Link>
                                </Nav.Item>
                            ))
                            }
                        </Nav>
                    </Col>

                    <Col xs={12} lg={10} className="proj-content px-0">
                        <Tab.Content className="proj-details h-100">
                            {projMultimedia.map((project, index) => (
                                <Tab.Pane eventKey={index} className="h-100"><ProjectCard key={project._id} project={project} /></Tab.Pane>
                            ))
                            }
                        </Tab.Content>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Tab.Container>
        }
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Basically it fetches data from my API and then filters it based on the category. If it returns a non empty array, it should render the project card. So far it is rendering fine but this error keeps showing on my browser console.
[image]

Any idea where I'm wrong?

Comment: You're not putting a unique key prop on each child in a list. See https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a unique `key` for each `<Nav.Item>`, like this:

```js
<Nav className="proj-nav d-lg-flex flex-lg-column">
    {
        projMultimedia.map((project, index) => (
            <Nav.Item key={index}>
                <Nav.Link eventKey={index}>{project.title}</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
        ))
    }
</Nav>
```

Same for `<Tab.Pane>`:

```js
{
    projMultimedia.map((project, index) => (
        <Tab.Pane key={index} eventKey={index} className="h-100"><ProjectCard key={project._id} project={project} /></Tab.Pane>
    ))
}
```

Comment: It fixed the error I shared. But now, it says: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `ProjectCard`.

Comment: Here is the code for the [ProjectCard.js](https://codepen.io/athens_lng/pen/OJBzQaP)

Comment: Can you show me the rendered ProjectCard keys

Comment: [Here](https://iili.io/HSkJUFa.png) is how it's showing, this is running on localhost only. And this is the rendered [page](https://iili.io/HSkdKPe.png). It's seems to be rendering fine? But why am I getting that "warning" or "error"...

Comment: Yeah it's just a warning, can you show me the `ProjectCard`s from the Inspector so I can see the keys rendered in html

Comment: [Here](https://iili.io/HSSSbl1.png) is the generated code of the `ProjectCard` upon rendering in the browser.

Comment: Make sure that `Tab.Pane` key ( `index` ) and `ProjectCard` key (`project._id`) are different in each loop, the keys must be unique in your page

Answer (score 0):

Inside map loops those returns/renders components, the first component should have an unique key, sometimes just using it's current index should work but sometimes you'll need to use some of your array data to make this id unique in the whole page.

```
<Nav className="proj-nav d-lg-flex flex-lg-column">
    {
        projMultimedia.map((project, index) => (
            // this is the First component so it should have an unique ID (current loop index in this case)
            <Nav.Item key={index}>
                <Nav.Link eventKey={index}>{project.title}</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
        ))
    }
</Nav>
```